# Множественный выбор в выпадающем списке с использованием Angular 5 и Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, angular, angular5, bootstrap4

Возникла необходимость сделать выпадающий список с возможностью множественного выбора (что-то вроде комбобокса с чекбоксами), и при этом связать его соответственно с переменной-массивом. Возможно ли это, если да, то каким способом?

Без Angular и Bootstrap нашел [такой способ.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547021/4838212) 
Также пробовал использовать `select` с набором `option`, но как их грамотно связать с моделью? И неудобно осуществлять выделение в списке без `checkbox`.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/417137/ первая ссылка в гугл

Comment: @overthesanity спасибо, с чекбоксами понятно, но как их внедрить в комбобокс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаю какая цель стоит перед вами в реализации комбобокса, поэтому приведу маленький пример с интеграцией этого [примера](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714705/how-to-use-checkbox-inside-select-option/27547021#27547021), от которого будем дальше отталкиваться. Пусть у нас будет `select` с чекбоксами того, что нужно сделать (`todo`):

```ts
// typings.d.ts

declare interface Todo {
    title: string;
    completed: boolean;
}
```

Создадим `reusable` компонент:

```ts
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-combobox',
    templateUrl: './combobox.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./combobox.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ComboboxComponent {
    @Input()
    public todos: Todo[] = [];

    public checkboxesShown = false;

    constructor(private host: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}

    public showCheckboxes(): void {
        this.checkboxesShown = !this.checkboxesShown;
    }

    public checkTodo(todo: Todo): void {
        this.host.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('checkTodo', {
            detail: todo
        }));
    }
}
```

Шаблон:

```
// combobox.component.html

<div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectbox" (click)="showCheckboxes()">
        <select>
            <option>Выбрать что-то</option>
        </select>

        <div class="over-select"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="checkboxes" *ngIf="checkboxesShown">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let todo of todos; let index = index">
            <label [attr.for]="index">
                <input type="checkbox" [attr.id]="index" [checked]="todo.completed" (change)="checkTodo(todo)">
                {{ todo.title }}
            </label>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>

<pre>{{ todos | json }}</pre>
```

Стили:

```css
// combobox.component.scss

.multiselect {
    width: 200px;

    .selectbox {
        position: relative;

        select {
            width: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .over-select {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    }

    .checkboxes {
        border: 1px #dadada solid;

        label {
            display: block;

            &:hover {
                background-color: #1e90ff;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

С этим компонентом мы будем взаимодействовать сверху - передавать ему `data-bound` свойства и слушать события:

```ts
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

function getTodos(length: number): Todo[] {
    return Array.from({
        length
    }).map(() => {
        return {
            title: 'Купить кофе',
            completed: false
        };
    });
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <app-combobox [todos]="todos" (checkTodo)="checkTodo($event)"></app-combobox>
    `,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {
    public todos: Todo[] = getTodos(10);

    public checkTodo({ detail }: CustomEvent): void {
        this.todos = this.todos.map((todo) => {
            if (todo === detail) {
                todo.completed = !todo.completed;
            }

            return todo;
        });
    }
}
```

Для примера я создал функцию, которая генерирует массив `todos` заданной длины, слушаем событие `checkTodo`, когда Angular вызовет наш метод - мы меняем ссылку на массив, потому что если компонент маркирован как `OnPush` - то механизм обнаружения изменений запустится в случае изменения ссылки на входное свойство. В итоге получаем следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стилизовать это вы можете как угодно на свое усмотрение, тут важно показать минимальную логику и подход, который нужно использовать, потому что в конечном итоге вы будете кастомизировать это под себя.

Comment: Никак не поборю ошибку `Type 'ElementRef' is not generic`, уже перепробовал разные версии ng-bootstrap, как советуют, например, здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50780419/angular-5-ng-bootstrap-type-elementref-is-not-generic-err  -  от 1.0.0 до 3.3.1. Сейчас использую Angular 5.2.8, typescript 2.7.2.

Comment: @Emm, ммм, да, `ElementRef` универсальный с 6 энгулара, уберите просто перегрузку типа `private host: ElementRef`

Comment: ага, спасибо, перезагрузку убрал, как тогда будет выглядеть тело метода `checkTodo(todo: Todo)` ? все остальное работает

Comment: @Emm, не понял вопроса про тело метода)

Answer (score -1):

Так в *angular material* есть select c option в виде checkbox, в чем проблема их использовать? К mat-select просто добавить свойство *multiple*. Вот здесь начиная с заголовка  "Multiple selection" есть примеры: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview.

Comment: это можно было бы использовать в проектах где используется сам material, а подключать пакет весом 1мб в прод сборке только из-за этого - плохое решение, к тому же с их дизайном

Comment: Тогда можно так: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-checkbox

Comment: зачем использовать нативные средства браузера (`getElementById`)?

Comment: вы правы, пример отредактирован.